# What does $p+q=k$ mean in the index of summation?

Tags: notation, homology-cohomology, graded-modules

I need help solving something I don't understand. OK so the problem is this:

$$H^k(X,C)=\bigoplus_{p+q=k} H^{p,q}(X),$$

What does the $\;p+q=k\;$ mean?

Thank you anybody that helps! :)

Comment: It means that you have to consider the sum with double indexes such that their sum is constant equals to $k$. For example, for $k=4$ you can take $p=1,q=3$ or $p=2=q$ and so on...

Comment: So as long as p+q=k it will do the thing AFTER it???

Comment: There is **no** need to use three question marks. Ever.

Comment: Use dollar signs `$` to write in TeX.

Comment: @ Mariano What the heck is that supposed to mean? I thought this was a sight for MATHEMATICS not English! And thank you Sigur

Comment: Let's please all be civil.

Comment: This is a site were humans communicate in English about math.

Comment: @vadim sorry I guess I got carried away and @ Mariano Yes I know, BUT I'm pretty sure it won't matter... :/ I'm good in mathematics not English.

Comment: Using punctuation correctly, not using CAPITALS unless in extraordinary need, being polite, not getting carried away in the first few minutes (or ever) and so on are very useful in making the most of this place.

Comment: So far I'm the only one who's up-voted the question, so the people who wrote the other two answers besides mine did not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$p+q = k$ indicates that the sum of indexes $p, q$ is equal to $k$, where $k$ is constant, for the given $k$.  If $k=4$ you can take $p=1, q=3$  or $p = q = 2,$ etc.

So every possible pair $(p, q)$ for which $p+q = k$; where $p, q$ are the indices which indicate which $H^{p, q}(X)$ to sum.

---

**From comment**

Indeed: to "spell it out the notation" you've posted, for a particular value of $k$, let's let $k = 4.\;$ Then:
$$H^4(X,C)=\bigoplus_{p+q=k} H^{p,q}(X) = H^{0, 4}(X) \oplus H^{1, 3}(X) \oplus H^{2,2}(X) \oplus H^{3,1}(X)\oplus H^{4,0}(X)$$

Comment: So it would set those for the variables? Right?

Comment: Hello? You still there?

Comment: I'm here...patience, please ;-)  We'd have, e.g., $H^4(X,C)=\bigoplus_{p+q=k} H^{p,q}(X) = H^{1, 3}(X) \oplus H^{2, 2}(X) \oplus ...$

Comment: Yes...it doesn't keep a sum of all $p + q$. Rahter it sums all the $H^{p, q}(X)$ for which $p + q = k$.

Comment: Ok, so it adds all of them then?

Comment: Yes. That's right. Be sure to understand what $\bigoplus H^{p, k}(X)$ denotes.

Comment: @Sonofmetal, just a question: do you know what is $H^k(X,C)$? I'm asking since it is strange if you know how to deal with it but without knowing that sum.

Comment: No I do not... Actually I'm tackling the problem without knowing much about it... Well that's how people learn what things are, right?

Comment: Indeed, sonofmetal...jump in and learn. We use $\bigcup$ to denote the union of many sets; we use $\bigcap$ to denote the intersection of many sets. We can use $\bigoplus$ to denote the direct sum of $H^{p, q}(X)$. Summing expressions uses the sigma notation, e.g.  $\sum_{k=1}^n n^2 = 1^2 + 2^2 + \cdots + n^2$. Ditto for long strings of products: $\Pi$ to shorten, say, $1\cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot \cdots \cdot (2n+1)$

Comment: @amWhy: More nice feedback! +1

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to indicate a summation (similarly with a product, direct summation, etc.)  In all cases, the sum is evaluated in all ways such that the condition is met, subject to natural restrictions that are implicit in the problem.  Typical restrictions are that the index is an integer, and sometimes that the index is nonnegative.

Examples: $$\sum_{i\ge 0} f(i)$$
and $$\sum_{i\in[0,6]}f(i)$$
and $$\sum_{j|n} f(j)$$
and $$\sum_{j|n, j\neq 3} f(j)$$
and $$\sum_{jk=n} f(j)f(k)$$
and $$\sum_{j+k=n} f(j)$$

Answer (score 1):

There is something to be said for writing
$$
\bigoplus_{p,\,q\, :\, p+q=k} H^{p,q}(X).
$$
For example, in case $k=3$, this would mean
$$
H^{0,3}(X) \oplus H^{1,2}(X)\oplus H^{2,1}(X)\oplus H^{3,0}(X)
$$
(or if only positive indices were indicated by the context, then discard the first and last terms, etc.).

Sometimes people write
$$
\sum_{i<j} a_{ij}
$$
when $j$ is fixed by the context and it means $i$ runs through the list of all values less than $j$.  But sometimes they mean the pair $i,j$ runs through the list of all values in which $i<j$, and neither is fixed.  It is sometimes convenient to make the notation explicit about the difference, writing
$$
\sum_{i\,:\,i<j} a_{ij}
$$
in one case, and
$$
\sum_{i\,j\,:\,i<j} a_{ij}
$$
in the other.